# Is Apache Spark SQL generally faster with a DELETE and INSERT, or a MERGE?

Tags: apache-spark, azure-synapse

If one only wants to insert new rows, not update existing ones: Is Apache Spark SQL generally faster with DROP TABLE and INSERT, or a MERGE & INSERT? Or some third option.

There's quite a bit written on traditional SQL, but I don't see much for Spark SQL.

If it depends...depends on what?

(I am working within Azure Synapse, writing to a Delta table, if that makes any difference0.

Comment: In merge statement it will compare the each row from one table to each row of another table line by line and if condition is fulfilled we are updating or inserting but in delete and insert it will dust delete the row which fulfilling condition and insert row without checking any thing so it will faster than merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DROP TABLE and INSERT would be relatively faster as MERGE and INSERT of Delta Lake involves JOIN operations (Inner Join and outer join), which makes the MERGE slower and costly[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just append and use a received timestamp or load id literal (should be in the first 32 columns) and you still retain the history (if cdc is enabled).  Perf wise max of the first 32 is held in the transaction log, nothing is thrown away unless you want to reduce data usage.

Dropping your data may be the right thing, but you should ask if you will ever need the previous data like, for example, part of the data source is missing and you roll yesterdays forward.